# Flutter integration testing : Enter text into TextFormField by label

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

How do I enter text into `TextFormField` by using the label text? My issue is that I can't find the widget while doing an integration test. I was able to find the widget by adding a key but I don't want to change the source code of the app for doing integration testing.

```
TextFormField(
                controller: usernameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(border: UnderlineInputBorder(), labelText: "Username"),
              )
```

Tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
final usernameField = find.descendant(
  of: find.text("Username"),
  matching: find.byType(EditableText),
);
```

Answer (score 6):

You were on the right track, just a couple of things needed adjusting.

## TLDR;

Try this instead:

```
final usernameField = find.ancestor(
  of: find.text('Username'),
  matching: find.byType(TextFormField),
);

tester.enterText(usernameField, "testing");
```

## Explanation

### Relationship between "Username" and `EditableText`

First off, the finder couldn't find an `EditableText` related to "Username" because the `EditableText` used by `TextFormField` is actually a *sibling/cousin* to any `Text` type widgets related to the decoration.

You can take a look at the tree using the Widget Inspector in most IDEs, or if you want to stay completely in the test environment, try [debugDumpApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/debugDumpApp.html) to have the tree output to the console. As you can see by this part of the tree, there's nothing under the `EditableText` that has the "Username" text in it.

#### `TextFormField` tree

```
│     └TextFormField(dependencies: [UnmanagedRestorationScope, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#1c7cf]], state: _TextFormFieldState#979c2)
│      └UnmanagedRestorationScope
│       └TextField(controller: TextEditingController#7d830(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1))), enabled: true, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Username", floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto, floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start, border: UnderlineInputBorder(), alignLabelWithHint: false), dependencies: [DefaultSelectionStyle, MediaQuery, UnmanagedRestorationScope, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#1c7cf]], state: _TextFieldState#b279d)
│        └MouseRegion(listeners: [enter, exit], cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text), renderObject: RenderMouseRegion#0773e relayoutBoundary=up3)
│         └TextFieldTapRegion(groupId: EditableText, renderObject: RenderTapRegion#81348)
│          └IgnorePointer(ignoring: false, renderObject: RenderIgnorePointer#4fd71 relayoutBoundary=up5)
│           └AnimatedBuilder(animation: TextEditingController#7d830(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1))), state: _AnimatedState#59a41)
│            └Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, tooltip: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#eb417 relayoutBoundary=up6)
│             └TextSelectionGestureDetector(state: _TextSelectionGestureDetectorState#c5ea6)
│              └RawGestureDetector(state: RawGestureDetectorState#1eae5(gestures: [tap, long press, pan], excludeFromSemantics: true, behavior: translucent))
│               └Listener(listeners: [down, panZoomStart], behavior: translucent, renderObject: RenderPointerListener#84fb6 relayoutBoundary=up7)
│                └AnimatedBuilder(animation: Listenable.merge([FocusNode#3118d(context: Focus), TextEditingController#7d830(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))]), state: _AnimatedState#6fcb9)
│                 └InputDecorator(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Username", hintMaxLines: "1", floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto, floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start, border: UnderlineInputBorder(), alignLabelWithHint: false), isFocused: false, isEmpty: true, dependencies: [Directionality, MediaQuery, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#1c7cf]], state: _InputDecoratorState#cdcb7(tickers: tracking 2 tickers))
│                  └_Decorator(renderObject: _RenderDecoration#543bf relayoutBoundary=up8)
│                   ├RepaintBoundary(renderObject: RenderRepaintBoundary#932e5 relayoutBoundary=up9)
│                   │└UnmanagedRestorationScope
│                   │ └EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#62cb3](controller: TextEditingController#7d830(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1))), focusNode: FocusNode#3118d, debugLabel: (englishLike titleMedium 2014).merge(blackMountainView titleMedium), inherit: false, color: Color(0xdd000000), family: Roboto, size: 16.0, weight: 400, baseline: alphabetic, decoration: TextDecoration.none, textAlign: start, keyboardType: TextInputType(name: TextInputType.text, signed: null, decimal: null), autofillHints: [], dependencies: [Directionality, MediaQuery, ScrollConfiguration, _EffectiveTickerMode], state: EditableTextState#1c1c0(tickers: tracking 1 ticker))
│                   │  └TextFieldTapRegion(debugLabel: EditableText, groupId: EditableText, renderObject: RenderTapRegion#9cbef)
│                   │   └MouseRegion(listeners: <none>, cursor: defer, renderObject: RenderMouseRegion#74908 relayoutBoundary=up11)
│                   │    └Actions(dispatcher: null, actions: {DoNothingAndStopPropagationTextIntent: DoNothingAction#4a34c, ReplaceTextIntent: CallbackAction<ReplaceTextIntent>#408b9, UpdateSelectionIntent: CallbackAction<UpdateSelectionIntent>#06984, DirectionalFocusIntent: DirectionalFocusAction#2491c, DismissIntent: CallbackAction<DismissIntent>#3e59f, DeleteCharacterIntent: _OverridableContextAction<DeleteCharacterIntent>#690f6(defaultAction: _DeleteTextAction<DeleteCharacterIntent>#0bc91), DeleteToNextWordBoundaryIntent: _OverridableContextAction<DeleteToNextWordBoundaryIntent>#c44ac(defaultAction: _DeleteTextAction<DeleteToNextWordBoundaryIntent>#119b9), DeleteToLineBreakIntent: _OverridableContextAction<DeleteToLineBreakIntent>#af3a8(defaultAction: _DeleteTextAction<DeleteToLineBreakIntent>#9eaed), ExtendSelectionByCharacterIntent: _OverridableContextAction<ExtendSelectionByCharacterIntent>#78905(defaultAction: _UpdateTextSelectionAction<ExtendSelectionByCharacterIntent>#3cb9a), ExtendSelectionToNextWordBoundaryIntent: _OverridableContextAction<ExtendSelectionToNextWordBoundaryIntent>#efea3(defaultAction: _UpdateTextSelectionAction<ExtendSelectionToNextWordBoundaryIntent>#11fdb), ExtendSelectionToLineBreakIntent: _OverridableContextAction<ExtendSelectionToLineBreakIntent>#9cdf0(defaultAction: _UpdateTextSelectionAction<ExtendSelectionToLineBreakIntent>#64825), ExpandSelectionToLineBreakIntent: _OverridableAction<ExpandSelectionToLineBreakIntent>#44e24(defaultAction: CallbackAction<ExpandSelectionToLineBreakIntent>#ce179), ExpandSelectionToDocumentBoundaryIntent: _OverridableAction<ExpandSelectionToDocumentBoundaryIntent>#1f49f(defaultAction: CallbackAction<ExpandSelectionToDocumentBoundaryIntent>#faeb6), ExtendSelectionVerticallyToAdjacentLineIntent: _OverridableContextAction<ExtendSelectionVerticallyToAdjacentLineIntent>#2444b(defaultAction: _UpdateTextSelectionToAdjacentLineAction<ExtendSelectionVerticallyToAdjacentLineIntent>#efbca), ExtendSelectionToDocumentBoundaryIntent: _OverridableContextAction<ExtendSelectionToDocumentBoundaryIntent>#a9b51(defaultAction: _UpdateTextSelectionAction<ExtendSelectionToDocumentBoundaryIntent>#d1374), ExtendSelectionToNextWordBoundaryOrCaretLocationIntent: _OverridableContextAction<ExtendSelectionToNextWordBoundaryOrCaretLocationIntent>#913d5(defaultAction: _ExtendSelectionOrCaretPositionAction#00b6c), ScrollToDocumentBoundaryIntent: _OverridableAction<ScrollToDocumentBoundaryIntent>#96e26(defaultAction: CallbackAction<ScrollToDocumentBoundaryIntent>#f52dc), SelectAllTextIntent: _OverridableContextAction<SelectAllTextIntent>#208ba(defaultAction: _SelectAllAction#1c128), CopySelectionTextIntent: _OverridableContextAction<CopySelectionTextIntent>#31482(defaultAction: _CopySelectionAction#d777b), PasteTextIntent: _OverridableAction<PasteTextIntent>#17ba0(defaultAction: CallbackAction<PasteTextIntent>#fc2e6), TransposeCharactersIntent: _OverridableAction<TransposeCharactersIntent>#909dc(defaultAction: CallbackAction<TransposeCharactersIntent>#826be)}, state: _ActionsState#6345b)
│                   │     └_ActionsMarker
│                   │      └_TextEditingHistory(state: _TextEditingHistoryState#c5c7e)
│                   │       └Actions(dispatcher: null, actions: {UndoTextIntent: _OverridableAction<UndoTextIntent>#76c57(defaultAction: CallbackAction<UndoTextIntent>#a6b68), RedoTextIntent: _OverridableAction<RedoTextIntent>#4244e(defaultAction: CallbackAction<RedoTextIntent>#d89b9)}, state: _ActionsState#a1a96)
│                   │        └_ActionsMarker
│                   │         └Focus(debugLabel: "EditableText", focusNode: FocusNode#3118d, dependencies: [_FocusMarker], state: _FocusState#f3479)
│                   │          └_FocusMarker
│                   │           └Scrollable(axisDirection: right, physics: null, restorationId: "editable", dependencies: [MediaQuery, UnmanagedRestorationScope, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#1c7cf]], state: ScrollableState#2fb51(position: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#ec8ce(offset: 0.0, range: 0.0..0.0, viewport: 800.0, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#259e6, ScrollDirection.idle), effective physics: ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics))
│                   │            └_ScrollableScope
│                   │             └Listener(listeners: [signal], behavior: deferToChild, renderObject: RenderPointerListener#dd2ea relayoutBoundary=up12)
│                   │              └RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#d6db0](state: RawGestureDetectorState#cda6b(gestures: <none>, excludeFromSemantics: true, behavior: opaque))
│                   │               └Listener(listeners: [down, panZoomStart], behavior: opaque, renderObject: RenderPointerListener#0abf9 relayoutBoundary=up13)
│                   │                └Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, tooltip: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#6f0e4 relayoutBoundary=up14)
│                   │                 └IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#f9ddb](ignoring: false, ignoringSemantics: false, renderObject: RenderIgnorePointer#015fc relayoutBoundary=up15)
│                   │                  └CompositedTransformTarget(renderObject: RenderLeaderLayer#bd9fd relayoutBoundary=up16)
│                   │                   └Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, tooltip: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#20253 relayoutBoundary=up17)
│                   │                    └_ScribbleFocusable(state: _ScribbleFocusableState#6511f)
│                   │                     └_Editable-[GlobalKey#9b870](dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#1c7cf]], renderObject: RenderEditable#7f9ac relayoutBoundary=up18)
│                   ├_Shaker(animation: AnimationController#c202f(⏮ 0.000; paused), state: _AnimatedState#77802)
│                   │└Transform(dependencies: [Directionality], renderObject: RenderTransform#053a1 relayoutBoundary=up9)
│                   │ └AnimatedOpacity(duration: 200ms, opacity: 1.0, state: _AnimatedOpacityState#bcd55(ticker inactive))
│                   │  └FadeTransition(opacity: AnimationController#04a30(⏮ 0.000; paused; for AnimatedOpacity)➩Cubic(0.40, 0.00, 0.20, 1.00)➩Tween<double>(1.0 → 1.0)➩1.0, renderObject: RenderAnimatedOpacity#05cbb relayoutBoundary=up10)
│                   │   └AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(duration: 200ms, debugLabel: (((englishLike titleMedium 2014).merge(blackMountainView titleMedium)).merge(unknown)).copyWith, inherit: false, color: Color(0x99000000), family: Roboto, size: 16.0, weight: 400, baseline: alphabetic, height: 1.0x, decoration: TextDecoration.none, softWrap: wrapping at box width, overflow: clip, state: _AnimatedDefaultTextStyleState#6c250(ticker inactive))
│                   │    └DefaultTextStyle(debugLabel: (((englishLike titleMedium 2014).merge(blackMountainView titleMedium)).merge(unknown)).copyWith, inherit: false, color: Color(0x99000000), family: Roboto, size: 16.0, weight: 400, baseline: alphabetic, height: 1.0x, decoration: TextDecoration.none, softWrap: wrapping at box width, overflow: clip)
│                   │     └Text("Username", textAlign: start, overflow: ellipsis, dependencies: [DefaultSelectionStyle, DefaultTextStyle, MediaQuery])
│                   │      └RichText(softWrap: wrapping at box width, overflow: ellipsis, maxLines: unlimited, text: "Username", dependencies: [Directionality, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#1c7cf]], renderObject: RenderParagraph#128a5 relayoutBoundary=up11)
│                   ├_HelperError(state: _HelperErrorState#ffb07(ticker inactive))
│                   │└SizedBox(renderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#8887a relayoutBoundary=up9)
│                   └_BorderContainer(dependencies: [Directionality], state: _BorderContainerState#c1c2f(tickers: tracking 2 tickers))
│                    └CustomPaint(renderObject: RenderCustomPaint#f9064)
```

### `ancestor` vs. `descendant`

Secondly, you needed to use `ancestor` instead of `descendant`. These two methods can be a bit difficult to wrap your head around, but this is how I think of it to keep them straight.

1. Start with your `of` finder
2. From your `of` method, is the thing you want your `matching` finder to find back up the tree (less indented), or are you going further down the tree (more indented)?

   - If you're going up, use `ancestor`
   - If you're going down, use `descendant`
3. The `ancestor`/`descendant` method will return what `matcher` defines, not what `of` defines

### Entering text

I'm taking a guess here, but I think that you were trying to find an `EditableText` because the documentation mentions needing one. Thankfully, it also mentions that you can use something which has a descendant `EditableText`.

As such, we can find a `TextFormField` instead of a `EditableText` in the `matching` parameter and still use that finder with the [enterText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/enterText.html) method.

Comment: Very good description and thanks a million for that. I found that using tester.enterText( etc simply did not work when the form was saved in the Integration Test. What did work was using a controller and that worked so well.

Answer (score 1):

- Pump your testwidget which contains your target TextFormField
- Then find all the TextFormFields in your widget, add it to the List.

```
List<TextField> textFields = List<TextField>();

find.byType(TextField).evaluate().toList().forEach((element) {
    textFields.add(element.widget);
});
```

- You now have all the textfields including Username labeled field